# converting the letter ي with ی

Tags: javascript

is there any way to convert Arabic ي to the Persian ي in React JS? I have an array of data in Persian language which contains the Arabic ي . and that's because of bad language support for Persian.

if I want to make a search functionality, I must enter ي instead ی and I can't force people to do this. how can I solve it?

there's a similar question here but with C#.

for example :

```
const items = ["ماشین","هواپیما","موبایل","کامپیوتر"]
const searchedItem = items.filter(item=>item==="ماشین")
```

in order to search "ماشین" (car) I need to type it with ي . it won't work with regular ی

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const items = ["ماشین","هواپیما","موبایل","کامپیوتر"]
const searchedItem = items.filter(item=>item==="ماشین" || item === 'ماشین'.replace(/ي/g, 'ی'))
console.log(searchedItem)
```

Comment: Thank you . will mark as correct answer. after 10 mins

Answer (score 1):

If you can, fix the data instead of putting a character replacement on the frontend.

Otherwise, if you have more than ten+ or unknown phrases with that character, and especially if you want fuzzy search... you're going to have to scan every character for each datum. Since strings are immutable, you could make a character array and then return the new filtered character instead.

Comment: actually, I get my data from ASP.NET backend API. they use an older version ASP. I must talk with our backend team. you are right